# Button text not visible fully in gridBagLayout

Tags: java, layout, gridbaglayout

I added main panel and next add to button panel to it. According to check box , select and deselect I change button text. but one text not visible fully.

[image: This is ok][image: error]

This is my lay out code.

```
    public RestartTreatmentDialog()
  {
    final GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[] { 0, 0 };
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[] { 0, 0, 0 };
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[] { 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[] { 1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };

    getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    final GridBagConstraints gbc_panel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_panel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_panel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_panel.gridx = 0;
    gbc_panel.gridy = 0;

    getContentPane().add(getTopPanel(), gbc_panel);

    final GridBagConstraints gbc_panel_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_panel_1.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gbc_panel_1.gridx = 0;
    gbc_panel_1.gridy = 1;

    getContentPane().add(getButtonPanel(), gbc_panel_1);
  }
```

This is button panel.

```
if (buttonPanel == null)
    {
      buttonPanel = new Panel();

      final GridBagLayout gbl_buttonPanel = new GridBagLayout();
      gbl_buttonPanel.columnWidths = new int[] { 0, 0, 0 };
      gbl_buttonPanel.rowHeights = new int[] { 0, 0 };
      gbl_buttonPanel.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
      gbl_buttonPanel.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };

      buttonPanel.setLayout(gbl_buttonPanel);

      final GridBagConstraints gbc_button = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc_button.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
      gbc_button.gridx = 0;
      gbc_button.gridy = 0;

      buttonPanel.add(getRestartButton(), gbc_button);

      final GridBagConstraints gbc_button_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc_button_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
      gbc_button_1.gridx = 1;
      gbc_button_1.gridy = 0;

      buttonPanel.add(getCancelButton(), gbc_button_1);
    }
```

[image: full panel]
I expect some expert help to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some solution:

1) set a fix bigger size for your left button, so when you cange size you have no problem [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536873/how-can-i-set-size-of-a-button)

2) cange button left to right and set the size like automatic 
[some code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485088/resizing-jbuttons-and-other-components-according-to-text)

Comment: I did not go too far in detail because I did not understand from your explanation if you are using SWING or JAVAFX

Comment: Francesco , I used SWING.